# How to extract a couple marked strings from a line (python)

Tags: python, string, extract, line

My Friends,

I spent quite some time on this one... but cannot yet figure out a better way to do it. I am coding in python, by the way.

So, here is a line of text in a file I am working with, for example:

">ref|ZP_01631227.1| 3-dehydroquinate synthase [Nodularia spumigena CCY9414]..."

How can I extract the two strings "ZP_01631227.1" and "Nodularia spumigena CCY9414" from the line?

The pairs of "| |" and brackets are like markers so we know we want to get the strings in between the two...

I guess I can probably loop over all the characters in the line and do it the hard way.  It just takes so much time...  Wondering if there is a python library or other smart ways to do it nicely?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> for line in open("file"):
...     if "|" in line:
...         whatiwant_1=line.split("|")[1]
...         if "[" in line:
...             whatiwant_2=line.split("[")[1].split("]")[0]
...
>>> print whatiwant_1 , whatiwant_2
ZP_01631227.1 Nodularia spumigena CCY9414
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I needed!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

One concise alternative is a regular expression (for some reason they have a bad rep in the Python community, but they do provide conciseness and power for simple text handling):

```
import re
s = ">ref|ZP_01631227.1| 3-dehydroquinate synthase [Nodularia spumigena CCY9414]..."
mo = re.search(r'\|(.*?)\|/*\[(.*?)\]', s)
if mo:
  thefirst, thesecond = mo.groups()
```

Comment: Did you mean to say `mo = re.search(r'\|(.*?)\|.*\[(.*?)\]', s)`?

Comment: As for the reason that regexps have a bad reputation in the Python community, I would suggest that the documentation is a little intimidating compared to, say, the Perl documentation (perlrequick).  A gentle tutorial filled with examples could usefully be added at the beginning of the current `re` documentation, for instance.

Comment: @gnibbler, yep, I'd dropped the `s`, tx for spotting, editing to fix.