# python: How to extract records from a natural language file only delimiter is 5 characters from the beginning of the record

Tags: python, parsing, text

I need to extract individual records from log files generated from a fairly archaic system and get them ready for database input. These flat files are all I can extract (and just formatting the query took weeks). Here is an example of a file with two records. The only delimiter I see is "/11 S11-" which is itself at a regular spot 5 characters in, but not quite at the beginning or end.

For those watching, yes, this is related to [my other newb question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855951/pyparsing-extract-variable-length-variable-content-variable-whitespace-substr). I have looked at the python documentation, some google results, and some [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474216/python-to-extract-data-from-a-file) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573698/how-to-extract-a-couple-marked-strings-from-a-line-python). So, my questions are

a) how to use a delimiter that starts 5 characters into the record?

b) how to grab these big chunks of natural language?

c) how to get rid of the whitespace after newlines? This is probably the easiest part: I can specify in the query how much long each field is. Right now, the accessionDate is 10 characters long, the accessionNumber is 10 characters long, the patMedicalRecordNum is 15 characters long. So the whitespace on the finalDxText is 35 characters.

```
01/01/11  S11-55555 20/444-55-6666 A.  PROSTATE AND SEMINAL VESICLES, PROSTATECTOMY:                           
                                   -  ADENOCARCINOMA.                                                      

                                   TOTAL GLEASON SCORE:  GLEASON 5+4=9                                     
                                   TUMOR LOCATION:  BILATERAL                                              
                                   TUMOR QUANTITATION:  15% OF PROSTATE INVOLVED BY TUMOR
                                   EXTRAPROSTATIC EXTENSION:  PRESENT AT RIGHT POSTERIOR                   
                                   SEMINAL VESICLE INVASION:  PRESENT                                      
                                   MARGINS:  UNINVOLVED                                                    
                                   LYMPHOVASCULAR INVASION:  PRESENT                                       
                                   PERINEURAL INVASION:  PRESENT                                           
                                   LYMPH NODES (SPECIMENS B AND C):                                        
                                      NUMBER EXAMINED:  25                                                 
                                      NUMBER INVOLVED:  1                                                  
                                      DIAMETER OF LARGEST METASTASIS:  1.7 mm                              
                                   ADDITIONAL FINDINGS:  HIGH-GRADE PROSTATIC INTRAEPITHELIAL NEOPLASIA,   
                                      ACUTE AND CHRONIC INFLAMMATION, INTRADUCTAL EXTENSION OF INVASIVE    
                                      CARCINOMA                                                            

                                   PATHOLOGIC STAGE:  pT3b N1 MX                                           

                               B.  LYMPH NODES, RIGHT PELVIC, EXCISION:                                    
                                   -  ONE OF SEVENTEEN LYMPH NODES POSITIVE FOR METASTASIS (1/17).         

                               C.  LYMPH NODES, LEFT PELVIC, EXCISION:                                     
                                   -  EIGHT LYMPH NODES NEGATIVE FOR METASTASIS (0/8).                     
01/02/11  S11-4444 20/111-22-3333 PROSTATE AND SEMINAL VESICLES, PROSTATECTOMY:                               
                                  - ADENOCARCINOMA.                                                        
                                    GLEASON SCORE:  3 + 3 = 6 WITH TERTIARY PATTERN OF 5.                                             
                                    TUMOR QUANTITATION:  APPROXIMATELY 10% BY VOLUME.                      
                                    TUMOR LOCATION:  BILATERAL.                                            
                                    EXTRAPROSTATIC EXTENSION:  NOT IDENTIFIED.                             
                                    MARGINS:  NEGATIVE.                                                    
                                    PERINEURAL INVASION:  IDENTIFIED.                                      
                                    LYMPH-VASCULAR INVASION:  NOT IDENTIFIED.                              
                                    SEMINAL VESICLE/VASA DEFERENTIA INVASION: NOT IDENTIFIED.              
                                    LYMPH NODES:  NONE SUBMITTED.                                          
                                    OTHER:  HIGH GRADE PROSTATIC INTRAEPITHELIAL NEOPLASIA.                
                                   PATHOLOGIC STAGE (pTNM):  pT2c NX.
```

Comment: NOTE: I removed the medical and bioinformatics tags since the question does not directly involve them. (It happens to be the subject of the text you are parsing but it is unrelated to how to parse it.)

Answer (score 2):

## Delimiters

I might be off the hook, but looking at your records and spefically at `01/01/11  S11-55555 20/444-55-6666`, `01/01/11` kinda looks like a date to me.

Therefore, judging from your input:

- You could check whether the line starts with a date (I'd say `mm/dd/yy` is the format here), using for instance a pretty straightforward regex and `re.match`.
- Looks like the data in each record is indented, so it looks like a line not being indented means it's a delimiter.

## Whitespace

`my_string.strip` returns `my_string` stripped of initial and trailing whitespace.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I'm more new that I let on. I'm a doctor trying to learn python to get some research done. I have used regular expressions about twice in the past. How would I use re.match in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this:

```
import re                                # regex module

in_string = """Text from above"""

records = []                             # list to store all records in order
record = ""                              # string to store current record

for line in in_string.splitlines():      # go through each line of the input
    if re.match('\d\d/\d\d/\d\d',line):  # match the date at the start 
        records.append(record)           # add current record to list
        record = ""                      # start new current record
    record += line.strip()               # add line (without whitespace) to current record
records.append(record)                   # add last record to records list
```

This outputs the following:

> ['',
>
> '01/01/11  S11-55555 20/444-55-6666 A.  PROSTATE AND SEMINAL VESICLES, PROSTATECTOMY:-  ADENOCARCINOMA.TOTAL GLEASON SCORE:  GLEASON 5+4=9TUMOR LOCATION:  BILATERALTUMOR QUANTITATION:  15% OF PROSTATE INVOLVED BY TUMOREXTRAPROSTATIC EXTENSION:  PRESENT AT RIGHT POSTERIORSEMINAL VESICLE INVASION:  PRESENTMARGINS:  UNINVOLVEDLYMPHOVASCULAR INVASION:  PRESENTPERINEURAL INVASION:  PRESENTLYMPH NODES (SPECIMENS B AND C):NUMBER EXAMINED:  25NUMBER INVOLVED:  1DIAMETER OF LARGEST METASTASIS:  1.7 mmADDITIONAL FINDINGS:  HIGH-GRADE PROSTATIC INTRAEPITHELIAL NEOPLASIA,ACUTE AND CHRONIC INFLAMMATION, INTRADUCTAL EXTENSION OF INVASIVECARCINOMAPATHOLOGIC STAGE:  pT3b N1 MXB.  LYMPH NODES, RIGHT PELVIC, EXCISION:-  ONE OF SEVENTEEN LYMPH NODES POSITIVE FOR METASTASIS (1/17).C.  LYMPH NODES, LEFT PELVIC, EXCISION:-  EIGHT LYMPH NODES NEGATIVE FOR METASTASIS (0/8).',
>
> '01/02/11  S11-4444 20/111-22-3333 PROSTATE AND SEMINAL VESICLES, PROSTATECTOMY:- ADENOCARCINOMA.GLEASON SCORE:  3 + 3 = 6 WITH TERTIARY PATTERN OF 5.TUMOR QUANTITATION:  APPROXIMATELY 10% BY VOLUME.TUMOR LOCATION:  BILATERAL.EXTRAPROSTATIC EXTENSION:  NOT IDENTIFIED.MARGINS:  NEGATIVE.PERINEURAL INVASION:  IDENTIFIED.LYMPH-VASCULAR INVASION:  NOT IDENTIFIED.SEMINAL VESICLE/VASA DEFERENTIA INVASION: NOT IDENTIFIED.LYMPH NODES:  NONE SUBMITTED.OTHER:  HIGH GRADE PROSTATIC INTRAEPITHELIAL NEOPLASIA.PATHOLOGIC STAGE (pTNM):  pT2c NX.']

Note: This is a crappy regular expression and will match any line that starts with "nn/nn/nn"

You'll probably want to add in a space between rows - something like `record += line.strip()+' '`

Good luck!

---

You can muck around with Regular Expressions (regex/re) [here](http://regexpal.com/) - put your regular expression (ie `\d\d/\d\d/\d\d  S11`) in the top box, and your text in the bottom one.

Comment: oh, wow, thanks guys. If I had 15 points of karma, I'd give you some.

Comment: You do now :-) interesting application, and congrats on self-learning from books!

Comment: Thanks! I wish I had at least one person to talk to in the flesh, but this is pretty close, and seems to have its own affordances.

Answer (score 1):

This is an idea:

```
 chunky = open(file, 'r')
    for line in chunky:
        if line>'00':                            # It's a starting line
            linedata = line.split(None, 3)       # separates line in four pieces
            chunk = linedata[3].strip()
        else:
            chunk += ' ' + line.strip()
```

And for a newb: a part of a string:  line[a:b] in which a is the first you need starting at 0 and b is the first you don't need. Your S11 would be linedata[1][0:3]